# Encrypted file to Remote Storage

Tags: file-encryption

Suppose I wanted to send some files to a remote storage device and (reasonably) guarantee their security and I am wondering whether something like the following method would be suitable:

Encrypt a file using symmetric encryption, encrypt its key using a local RSA key-pair, then upload the files over a secure channel like SSL.

An additional question is whether to create file digests for each of the encrypted files so that a file's integrity can be later verified, and how best to store those digests (presumably their security is also important to reduce the likelihood of people figuring out a file's content)?

Many thanks,

Cheers,

Geof.

Comment: You don't need Asymmetric phase and digestion if the files are encrypted good enough by symmetric encryption.

Comment: The asymmetric phase is not to re-encrypt the symmetric encryption, it is to encrypt the symmetric encryption key in a separate file.

Comment: Yes but why do you need to store the key on remote storage? Anyway to should keep the private key locally so keep the symmetric key instead and cut off the redundant process.

Comment: Yes, that is a fair point.

Comment: Is there a particular reason, why you want to roll your own encryption scheme instead of using one of the tools which provide that functionality?

Comment: Are you referring to a tool such as Encrypto?